# Azure chat bot using QnAMaker - Should Greet users with respect to current user's timezone

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I'm developing a Chat Bot in C# using Azure Bot Framework (v4),Currently I have a setup to display a welcome text which is used to greet the user.

**Current Greetings /welcome text:-**
*Hi User, I'm Bot.
How can I help you today.*

**current Code:**

```
protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        foreach (var member in membersAdded)
        {
           if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
         {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hi  **{member.Name**. I am Bot." {welcomeText}), cancellationToken);

           }
        }

    }
```

Now I want my bot to detect the current login user's timezone and greet him as per timings.

**Expected Greetings /welcome text:(when user chats at morning)** 
*Hi user, Good Morning .! I'm Bot.
How can i help you today.*

**Expected Greetings /welcome text:(when user chats at evening)** 
*Hi user, Good Evening.! I'm Bot.
How can i help you today.*

I want to make use of QnAmker or the default welcome text used in the bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are trying to get `user local time` and based on that you would like your `bot` to greet the user. You could try below code snippet:

```cs
protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

                    DateTime utcTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();

                    TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("China Standard Time");

                    DateTime yourLocalTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, cstZone);


                    if (yourLocalTime.Hour <= 12)
                    {

                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hello {member.Name}, good morning"), cancellationToken);
                    }
                    else if (yourLocalTime.Hour > 12)
                    {

                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hello {member.Name}, good afternoon"), cancellationToken);
                    }
                    else if (yourLocalTime.Hour > 17)
                    {

                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hello {member.Name}, good evening"), cancellationToken);
                    }
                    else
                    {                      
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hello {member.Name} " + yourLocalTime), cancellationToken);
                    }


                }
            }
        }
```

> **Note:** As you know each zone has its own time frame so  you could refer this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?view=netframework-4.8) for further customization. I have
>   shown `China Standard Time` for example. You could customize as per
>   your requirement.

For further customization you could follow below `interface` on screen shot. Just explore it by pressing `F12` on `FindSystemTimeZoneById` on above mentioned code.

[image]

Hope this would help.

Comment: @Kiron, thanks for the solution , that worked for me, i made the necessary customization and made it worked as per my requirement.

Comment: Great solution, do you know if the same TimeZoneInfo and convertTime are available in nodejs?

Comment: Also I might suggest that you use Switch/Case here instead of if/else, though functionally I don't think it matters.

Comment: @billoverton `switch (yourLocalTime.Hour)
                    {
                        case int time when time <= 12:
                            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hello {member.Name}, good morning"), cancellationToken);
                            break;
                        case int time when time > 12:
                            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hello {member.Name}, good afternoon"), cancellationToken);
                            break;
                    }`

Comment: Additionally, I am not sure about node.js library.

Answer (score 0):

This information is Channel specific. It is passed in the Activity ChannelData property